# How do I include form data in email to SUBMITTER?

Tags: forms, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to include in the email notification to the **submitter/user** (person filling out the form) the form the data from the form that the  put into the form.
I found this tutorial on including it in the email to myself as the owner of the form (http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/), and it works great, but I want to send that information to the person who filled out the form.

I have tried replacing this code:

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```

with this code:

```
var email = e.namedValues["Email Address"].toString();
```

That doesn't seem to be the trick. I double-checked the field name in the form/response spreadsheet, and it does match "Email Address." I also made that a required field in the form.

Could someone assist me with this?

Comment: This is would be helpful to you: http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/

Comment: That is helpful for sending it to myself, but it doesn't send it to the person who filled out the form. Do you have another link, or can you suggest the code I need to put in place for the email? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the each column in iteration....

if the column is email - address column then you need to assign to email variable.

here you need to assign

```
  for ( var keys in columns ) 
  {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if(columns[keys] == "Email Address")
      {
          email = e.namedValues[key].toString();
      }
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) 
      {
          message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
      }
  }
```